# ZeroMQ for Android

Tags: android, zeromq

Trying to compile ZeroMQ for Android 
below script, 
$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = /Users/user/android-ndk-r8b

```
OPTS=${1}
export DEVROOT="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT"
export SDKROOT="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/standalone_toolchain"
export AS="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as" 
export ASCPP="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as" 
export AR="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar" 
export RANLIB="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib" 
export CC="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc" 
export CXX="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++" 
export LD="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld" 
export STRIP="$SDKROOT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip" 
export LIBRARY_PATH="$SDKROOT/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="" 
export CFLAGS=" Wno-psabi --sysroot=$SDKROOT/ -I$SDKROOT/sysroot/usr/include -march=armv7-a -lstdc++ -Wvariadic-macros -Wlong-long -mfpu=vfp -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,-noexecstack -Wshadow"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS" 
export LDFLAGS="--sysroot=$SDKROOT/ -lstdc++ -L$SDKROOT/sysroot/usr/lib/ "
cmd="./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --host=arm-linux-androideabi $
{OPTS}
--disable-version" 
eval $
{cmd}
echo "privet "
make
mkdir -p $
{INSTALL_PATH}
make install
```

The error is:

```
Making all in src
make all-am
CXX libzmq_la-address.lo
In file included from address.cpp:21:0:
address.hpp:24:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libzmq_la-address.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory ...
Making install in src
CXX libzmq_la-address.lo
In file included from address.cpp:21:0:
address.hpp:24:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [libzmq_la-address.lo] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

configure works ok, but then I've that trouble... T_T

WHAT I'M DOING WRONG?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?